# athena-cloudwatch connector - you do NOT own the spill bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena

I am trying to query my cloudwatch logs thru athena. For that, I have deployed a pre-built version of the connector (Amazon Athena Cloudwatch Connector) from AWS SAR.

When I try to run a simple query in athena, I am getting the following error:

`GENERIC_USER_ERROR: Encountered an exception[java.lang.RuntimeException] from your LambdaFunction[athenacloudwatch] executed in context[retrieving meta-data] with message[You do NOT own the spill bucket with the name: s3://my-bucket-blalablaba/]`

The role that was created and is used by the lambda function has read/write access to this bucket. Bucket is not encrypted and does not have any kind of deny policy.

Again, no changes where made to the stack that is provided when the app was deployed.

any idea what I might be missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: In my case the bucket did not exist yet. Just as embarassing but the error message is misleading in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the name of Spill Bucket in your Lambda function connector from `s3://my-bucket-blalablaba/` to `my-bucket-blalablaba`.

Comment: this feels embarrassing...but yes...that was the problem. thank you!